# How to create several instances of django-leaflet with for loop?

Tags: python, django, leaflet, geodjango, django-leaflet

I want to create several instances of django-leaflet map with for loop and provide different lat and lon for each of them.
Just to mention; every sportclub object has a location field which is PointField
simply I want to have something like this but this code does not work as it should and it just shows one map with it's mark instead of one map for every object:

```
{% for sportclub in sportclubs %}
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="map_init" %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
          function map_init(map, options) {
              var lon = "{{ sportclub.location.x }}";
              var lat = "{{ sportclub.location.y }}";
              map.setView([lat, lon], 12  );
              L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
          }
      </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining the `map_init` function on every iteration of the for loop, try giving each function a unique name

```
{% for sportclub in sportclubs %}
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="map_init_{{ sportclub.id }}" %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function map_init_{{ sportclub.id }}(map, options) {
          ...
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it does not work. even when I try to show a leaflet instance without callback name inside loop, it shows only one map.